# Find those columns which have different values in different rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 450 fields/columns in my table and two rows, and I want to find which columns have different values in these rows.

Let's say I have the following table:

| dept | role1 | role2 | DEF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | abc | er | 0 |
| a | abc | er | 1 |

Here, we have diff value for DEF field but let say we do not know that, to find that which column has diff value can someone suggest me a query?

Comment: Can you suggest me solution for psql?

Comment: try the option of unpivoting and grouping

Comment: can you give one example here

Comment: check out my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jsonb functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to get rows as json objects and compare them:

```
select key as column, array_agg(value) as values
from my_table t
cross join jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t))
group by key
having count(distinct value) > 1

 column | values
--------+--------
 def    | {0,1}
(1 row)
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=be6445bec12822496674e84b7104efad)

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot and grouping is a way to get this done.

Here is an example on how to do this

```
create table t(dept varchar(10),role1 varchar(10),role2 varchar(10),DEF int)

insert into t 
select 'a','abc','er',0 union all
select 'a','abc','er',1 

select col_name,string_agg(f,',')
from (
 select unnest(array[role1,role2,cast(DEF as varchar(10))]) f
        ,unnest(array['role1','role2','DEF']) as col_name
  from t
     )x
group by col_name
having count(distinct f)>1



+----------+------------+
| col_name | string_agg |
+----------+------------+
| DEF      |        0,1 |
+----------+------------+

db-fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f884b85657218982da90b50328883e66
```